# Saving values in kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I wrote an small kivy program, because I wanted to learn how to save values using .json files.
I checked out the documetation and found this:http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html#module-kivy.storage
I tried to to it similar,but I got the error:`ImportError: No module named storage.jsonstore`

Why doesn't it work?

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Layout(BoxLayout):
    def save(self, vinput):
        store = JsonStore('hello.json')
        store.put('tito', inpud=vinput)

ROOT = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id:my_textinput
    Button:
        text: 'save'
    Button:
        text: 'acsess'

''')


class Caption(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 1, 1)
        return ROOT

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Caption().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used JsonStore before, I will have a look at it, then will update the answer, but for now, you could do it this way.

```
import json

#If you want to write in your JSON file.
out_file = open("your_file.json","w")
json.dump(result,out_file, indent=4)
   # result ^ contains your data.
   # indent = 4 is to make your file more readable.
out_file.close()

#If you want to read your JSON file.

in_file = open("your_file.json","r")
result = json.load(in_file)
in_file.close()
```

**EDIT: 1**

It actually works perfectly fine. 
Try this improved code.

Your .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Lay_out(BoxLayout):
    def save(self, vinput):
        store = JsonStore('hello.json')
        store.put('tito', inpud=vinput)

class CaptionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Lay_out()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CaptionApp().run()
```

Your .kv file

```
<Lay_out>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id:my_textinput
    Button:
        text: 'save'
        on_release: root.save(my_textinput.text)
    Button:
        text: 'acsess'
```

Comment: Ahh, I get it, my kivy version is my problem